# How can I add a new key/value to session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

Need to keep track of a user as they navigate through a website using `session`. I tried to add a new key/value into session but its only seen locally, as I redirect to another controller the user_id key is gone. Everything im reading tells me to use `session[:user_id] = @user.id`. Once the user is redirected to another page I should be able to call `session[:user_id]` and identify the user by `User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])` However after `redirect to '/tweets'` and calling `session` there is no `:user_id` key anymore.

```
post '/signup' do
if params[:username] == "" || params[:email] == "" || params[:password] == ""
  redirect to '/signup'
else
  @user = User.create(params)
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  redirect to '/tweets'
end
```

Is there a way to add in my key/value into a session hash that persists until I use `session.clear`?

Comment: `session[:user_id]` uses the key that your session manager probably already uses to track users. Hence something in your cookie system may be overwriting it. Save a different key, such as `session[:my_user_id]` to see if that helps. And your tests can access this system thru `request.session`, to see what's going on.

Comment: Unless you close your browser or end the session you should have access. To keep track use the user.id and request.env['PATH_INFO'] to get the path. Try in other browser. It's weird

Comment: I have a theory. In your ApplicationController does it say `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` or just `protect_from_forgery`? The former should be used or else session will be replaced with null with each page load.

Comment: @Phlip, I tried to rename the key and still experiencing the same issue. I am going through some websites now to learn more about sessions to see if I can find the cause. Appreciate the feedback

Comment: @oMiKeY No I only have enable :sessions then set :sessions_secret, "secret", I will look into `protect_with_fogery with: :exception` to see if this is my issue. Thanks

Comment: write some automated "functional" tests that use `request.session`. Much easier than manual debugging.